how to claim all possible implementations of an existing component?
Let's suppose that my claim has two components: A and B.
Let's suppose that component B is the novel inventive step.
Let's suppose that component A is a method that outputs a list of recommended content based on user input, such as a search engine.
In other words, component A already exist, and it doesn't matter how A is implemented. My invention just needs any variant of A.
In the specifications, how do I state this fact, so that the claim will not trigger a means plus function for interpreting component A?
Would this work:

Various methods and algorithms exist in the prior art for determining recommended content. The most common among them may be the use of strict filters. However, it should be appreciated that the invention herein is not limited to any specific method for determining recommended content, but rather encompasses any variant of a content recommendation process, regardless of the specific implementation or algorithm used.

Would the above wording in the specifications avoid means plus function interpretation?

In software the answer is mostly no, because what is left after removing MPF interpretation is just purely functional claiming. Is there some reason you can't focus the claim on B and omit A? For example, A method for filtering a list of recommended content, comprising: ...

@bhuff36 so using your preamble, A method for filtering a list of recommended content, comprising:, if one of the steps is "identifying recommended content of the plurality of content in the database satisfying at least a first condition of passing at least one specified preference of the user;", would this trigger means plus function interpretation? Specially, would the wording "pass" a preference be ambiguous enough to trigger MPF?

_Bear: I think we've been over this before. Don't try to put "small" algorithmic steps in a claim. They are prone to get MPF and if you have no further breakdown indefiniteness. Embrace MPF, put high-level goals in the claim with MPF, and offer stepwise breakdown for them in the specification.

No such thing as means plus fiction in a method claim.

In a method claim there is no such thing as means-plus-function. There is an analogous step-plus-function. It is very rarely raised in practice.
Methods do not have components, they have steps which are “acts” not things.
A step like “sorting the list” is very common and would be taken at face value and apply to any way of sorting the list.
See this law review article.
Or this simpler explanation at a law firm
site.

I don't think it works that way. I believe there is an analogous bound on functional claiming in a method step as in claiming an apparatus element. The presumptions etc should apply equivalently to both. Your second reference supports this view while your first is quite old and I have not read it in detail.

I mean the above, of course, for computer-implemented methods (other types of methods might allow more functional claiming). The problem with computer inventions is it is always a method. Even it is claimed as a device containing programming what is being recited after the "programmed to" part is a basically a method. I would expect if it is MPF in the one it is MPF (or SPF) in the other.

It might make sense but it isn’t the case. There are extremely few step plus function cases. It really does not come up as an issue in the typical case. From the second link “ There seems to be a reluctance for courts to apply step-plus-function interpretations to process claims. This is true even when corresponding device claims reciting the same functions are interpreted under the means-plus-function provision of 112(f).@

I will research this further when I have more time, but I find it extremely unlikely that a delicate balance has been established for machine claims but method claims allow unbounded functional claiming as "acts" (in computer-related inventions).

https://klarquist.com/patent-defenses/1126f-claim-language/ This page lists a bunch of cases where 112f had been applied to method claims. The relevant inquiry appears to be whether the term would not connote acts to a person of skill sufficient to perform the recited function. Thus when one considers the average functionally stated computer implemented method limitation it is a function, not an act, and subject to 112f. Sorting may be simple enough that it would avoid this, but such is the exception rather than the norm.
